# How to correctly do a loading screen using react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, loading

I have always done loading screens using an individual component, either with `Loading...`text or a spinner of some sort

then imported this component in and rendered the app with a state of loading set to true until the component has mounted and changed the state to false. however I'm having an issue here which can only be solved with setting a timeout in component did mount, something I want to avoid as it means the app is taking longer to load than necessary in some scenarios

please see a gif of what's happening: https://makeagif.com/gif/-dyW3DE

it's showing the bag as empty flickering before it then shows the update part. I would like it to say loading right until the bag is the correct redux state and then display it

code so far

```
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     this.setState({ isLoading: false })
  }


return isLoading ? ( <div> Loading... </div>) : (
    <div>
      <h4> Bag </h4>
      <Modal /> 
     // other bag stuff here
      <p> Bag total: £{this.bagTotal(bag.products)}</p>
    </div>
  )
```

I want to eventually move this to the redux state but that is not necessary for now (maybe??)

any ideas?

Comment: This no need of redux.

Comment: @MohamedSameer I know but why's it not working at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that thing without using the redux its not necessary to use. If u call any `Http API request` or using the `setTimeout`.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        console.log("response :", response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        console.log("error :", error);
      });

    //or using setTimeout
     setTimeout(
        function() {
         this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }.bind(this),
       3000
     );
  }

  render() {
    let { isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {isLoading ? (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3zlqz04o0)

Comment: ah so I use redux to do my axios request so I should move it all to there?

Comment: u can manage like this but its need to dispatch the redux action and manage its.

Answer (score 0):

when u move that to redux then just dispatch the function to change the value of isLoading and connect state to the component using mapStateToProps, when the value gets updated in the store the component will automatically show loading bar